# can't restart docker after resetting the docker socker using docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

Tags: docker

I want to open the docker on a port, so I used this command :

```
service docker stop
docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d &  

INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()                    
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on tcp (0.0.0.0:2375)     
INFO[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANOTHER IP ADDRESS THAN 127.0.0.1 IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)           
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
................
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.4.1 5bc2ff8; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: aufs 
INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()                     
INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)  


service docker start
```

The first time it works, the port is open from 2375.

but now after using this command to open the port 2375 on the docker, docker can't open again using `service docker start`, the docker always stays in the status of stop.

I used `netstat -pna | 2375`, there is no program listening to 2375

anyone knows why I can't restart docker

---

### Update

I followed the advice to update the /etc/default/docker config,here is the update.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -H :2375"
```

then I restart the docker by `service docker restart` , it seems to be working because `service docker status` shows to be running, I thought it should take effect now. but when I used `docker images & docker ps -a`, it shows

> FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/images/json: dial
>   unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying
>   to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

when I go back to the docker config, remove the part '-H :2375' in the  DOCKER_OPTS, restart the docker, and it works well again. any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting docker twice. The first time with your custom port, and the second time via the `service` command. In order to put this custom port into your running configuration, you need to set `DOCKER_OPTS` environment variable to contain the `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` (or just `-H :2375` for short). [Here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3127) is a link to a Github issue which gives you a couple clues to setting this environment variable permanently. On CentOS, edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and add your custom port information to the `DOCKER_OPTS` there. On Ubuntu, as mentioned in the link, you can edit `/etc/default/docker` and add the correct information to the environment variable there. This way, docker should retain your custom port configuration when you `service docker start`. After this change, you can drop the custom `docker ... -d &` command and stick with starting it normally as a service with `service docker start`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. but after the command, still failing to restart the docker.

Comment: Oh. I think what's happening here is that you're running `docker -d` and then starting it again with `service docker start`. Try omitting the last command and then do a `netstat -tpal` to verify that you're running the docker daemon on the port you specify.

Comment: Yes, you are right, since I input docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d & , then used netstat -tapen | grep ":2375 " to check port 2375, there is docker process on 2375 now.  so now what should I do, my purpose is just to have a docker with port openning on 2375

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct information for making this custom port permanent.

Comment: Thanks, L0j1k, I thought it should be fine, the docker can start running, but for some reason,  it tells me var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory

Comment: Try running it with an explicit variable like `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` and you might also want to include your `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.